# Changing EntryElement keyboard returnkeytype monotouch.dialog

Tags: iphone, ios, xamarin.ios, monotouch.dialog

I'm using this code for changing the keyboard `returnkeytype` of the entry element in `monotouch.dialog` but it yet show 'return' on the keyboard.

```
    protected override MonoTouch.UIKit.UITextField CreateTextField (System.Drawing.RectangleF frame)
    {
        try {
            var field= base.CreateTextField (frame);
            field .ReturnKeyType = UIReturnKeyType.Done;
            return field ;
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            RltLog .HandleException (ex);
            return null ;
        }
    }
```

Am I wrong in some thin

Comment: how is that code snippet invoked ? could you share a bit more code ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By Looking on monotouch.dialog source codes I find that the elemet, itself has a attribute for this porpose. so should use a code like this:

```
RltEntryElement createServerUrlEntry(){

        try {


            ServerNameEntryElement = new EntryElement ("Website url","placeholder",
        "value");


            ServerNameEntryElement .ReturnKeyType = UIReturnKeyType .Done ;

            return ServerNameEntryElement ;

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            HandleException (ex);
            return null ;
        }
    }
```